# Resource: aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block complains about root module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
# TF Module to declare S3

resource "aws_kms_key" "lake_s3bucket_key" {
  description             = "This key is used to encrypt bucket objects"
  deletion_window_in_days = 30
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "log_bucket" {
  bucket = "test-log-bucket"
  acl    = "log-delivery-write"
}


# Data Lake bucket 
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "lake_s3bucket" {
  bucket = "ingestraw"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "s3bucket"
    Environment = "prod"
  }

  versioning {
    enabled = false
  }

  logging {
    target_bucket = aws_s3_bucket.log_bucket.id 
    target_prefix = "log/"
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.lake_s3bucket_key.arn
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}

# S3 bucket-level Public Access Block configuration
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "lake_s3bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.ingestraw.id

  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}
```

Terraform upon executing "terraform plan" throws below error:

Error: Reference to undeclared resource

on main_s3.tf line 45, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "lake_s3bucket":
45:   bucket = aws_s3_bucket.ingestraw.id

A managed resource "aws_s3_bucket" "ingestraw" has not been declared in
the root module.

I am new to terraform and hence not able to understand what is going wrong, why it is complaining about the root module. I am using Terraform 3.20.

Comment: You don't have a resource called `aws_s3_bucket.ingestraw`. Instead that resource is called `aws_s3_bucket.lake_s3bucket` and is defined by the line: `resource "aws_s3_bucket" "lake_s3bucket" {`

Comment: Okay, thanks this tip worked. So just for through understanding, I should use resources addressing as mentioned in the link instead of using the actual bucket name? which makes total sense to me(https://www.terraform.io/docs/internals/resource-addressing.html)

Comment: Yep. Terraform always refers to resources by the optional module names (potentially nested), the resource type and then the resource name.